# Duplicate POST Requests from Facebook Messenger/Bot API

Tags: node.js, facebook, bots

I keep getting double requests on to my webhook when trying to create a Facebook bot. I don't know why or how to stop this. My code seems standard.

I'm using the request module in Node.js to send responses.

Is this a known issue or is there a Node based way to mitigate this?

Comment: Please provide a minimal example of your code.

Answer (score 6):

I've been seeing multiple deliveries on my bots for two reasons:

- FB seems to have a 15 second timeout on webhook requests. That is, if your webhook does not return a `200 - OK` within 15 seconds, FB will retry to request a second time.
- Like @iownthegame wrote, if you register for the `message_deliveries` event, FB will send you delivery receipts.

One way to handle duplicate deliveries is to keep track of the last `seq` value that your bot saw. Obviously if you are load balancing webhooks requests across a pool of servers (eg on Heroku), you will have to share the last seen `seq` value across all your instances.

Answer (score 1):

Did you also register for the **message_deliveries** event for your webhook? If yes it will send you the message deliveries for confirmation.