# Sequential Message Sending Using Facebook Send-API

Tags: node.js, facebook, axios, q, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm trying to send messages using FB Send-Message API in sequential order, but have an issue with it. As a result my bot sends messages in wrong order. I have the following functions:

```
function sendMessage(recipient, payload, accessToken) {

    return axios.post(baseURL + 'v2.11/me/messages/?access_token=' + accessToken,
        Object.assign({}, {
            messaging_type: "RESPONSE",
            recipient: {
                id: recipient
            }
        }, payload) );
}
```

(1)(returns Promise of sending message);

```
let async_actions;
let promise_chain = Q.fcall(function(){});
async_actions = flow['messages'].map(message => {
    return sendMessage(recipient, message['payload'], flow['page']['accessToken'])
});


async_actions.forEach(async_action => {
    //console.log(async_action)
    promise_chain = promise_chain.then(f);
});
```

(2)(Loops through array with messages and executes function (1), then inserts it in a chain).

What should I do to send messages sequentially? For now it sends them randomly, I mean how to wait until one message is sent and then send another? Thank you.

Same issue: 
(1) [Facebook Messenger bot not sending messages in order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37152355/facebook-messenger-bot-not-sending-messages-in-order)

Comment: Do you understand what `async` means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a Facebook bug reported here - https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/565416400306038

```
function sendMessage(recipient, messages, accessToken, i) {


    axios.post(baseURL + 'v2.11/me/messages/?access_token=' + accessToken,
        Object.assign({}, {
            messaging_type: "RESPONSE",
            recipient: {
                id: recipient
            }
        }, messages[i]['payload']) )
        .then(response => {

            if(i < messages.length) sendMessage( recipient, messages, accessToken, i+1 );

            },
            error => {})
        .catch(error => {});

}
sendMessage(recipient, flow['messages'], flow['page']['accessToken'], 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `sendMessage`, it will return a promise before the promise is actually resolved. Therefore, you don't want to call the next `sendMessage` until the previous `sendMessage` call resolves. However, in your `.map()` call you do exactly that. Instead, you want to return a *function* that will call the correct `sendMessage`

Simplest way would be to use a [sequential promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-sequential) library, or you can roll your own using `reduce()`.

```
const sequential = require('promise-sequential');

const async_actions = flow['messages'].map(message => {
    // return a *function* which executes sendMessage when the function is called
    return () => {
      console.log(`sending message ${message['payload']}`);
      sendMessage(recipient, message['payload'], flow['page']['accessToken'])
    };
});


sequential(async_actions)
  .then(res => {
    console.log("all done");
    console.log(res);
  });
```

Comment: Worked first time I've executed, but for now continues sending messages in random order. (did exactly the same, you suggested above).

Comment: it was fb bug reported here - https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/565416400306038

Comment: your console.log(`sending message ${message['payload']}`); worked properly and requests were sent to facebook in proper order, but message order was anyway wrong, I've solved problem using recursion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48352743/5880255